# Based on Dynamic DropDown selection Pagination not working in Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter, dropdownbox

I want to add a drop down to the CodeignIter pagination so that the user could select items per page himself.

But the value of $config['per_page'] dosen't change. After I click on page 2 the default value is considered.

Any help how could I accomplish this. in future I also want to add search and sort by name to this grid. So the solution should be an appropriate one.

Here are my files.

Controller:

```
    <?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class products extends CI_Controller {
    public $ipp = 5;
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('productmodel');
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        // $this->load->model(array('usermodel','categorymodel'));
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/just4ad/index.php/products/index';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all_results('jobs');

        if(!empty($this->input->post('sel'))){
            $this->ipp = $this->input->post('sel');
        }

        $config['per_page'] = $this->ipp;
        $start = end($this->uri->segments);
        $end = $config['per_page'];

        if(empty($start) || $start == 1){
            $start = 0;
        }

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['product_data'] = $this->productmodel->getAllProducts($end, $start);
        $this->load->view('index', $data);
    }
}
```

Model:

```
<?php
class productmodel extends CI_Model {

    var $title   = '';
    var $content = '';
    var $date    = '';

    function getAllProducts($limit = '',$start = '')
    {
        if($limit != '' && $start != '' && $start != 0){
            $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        }else if($limit != '' && $start == 0){
            $this->db->limit($limit);
        }
        $result = $this->db->get('jobs');
        $data = $result->result_array();
        return $data;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I think this plugin is useful for you. http://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html

Comment: Thanks for ur help Girish.It was similar to my app but i want to do it in CodeIgnitor.

Comment: Yo can use codeigniter instead of sever side. use ajax URL as codeigniter url and process those details in controller and model as well